# Directed Weighted Graph with no cycles - LP

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have directed weighted graph. I have to find a set of edges with minimal sum of their weights that without the set graph becomes acyclic. I can call lp solver multiple times.

I'm kind off lost on this one. The first thing that I thought of was to have variable x ∈ {0,1} for each edge and write a condition for each possible cycle that at least one edge has to be in the set. But that is really really slow.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the weights are non-negative, then you can choose the empty set of edges to get minimum weight zero. If you allow negative weights, then clearly you can choose the set of all edges with negative weights and you are done.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that without the set graph becomes acyclic. I edited the question